# visual studio git stopped detecting changes - cannot commit

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I am using git inside of Visual Studio. I am doing an MVC project and using git locally, I have already made 4 commits but today I see that after I went to `changes` to commit the changes from today (and there were many files changed), the `Commit All` button is greyed out and there are no files under `changes`.

Specifically I am using VS 2015 CE.

[image]

```
git status

On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   CMS/App_Data/CMS.mdf
        modified:   CMS/App_Data/CMS_log.ldf
        modified:   CMS/Areas/Admin/Controllers/CmsController.cs
        modified:   CMS/Areas/Admin/Views/Cms/Index.cshtml
        modified:   CMS/CMS.csproj
        modified:   CMS/Content/Site.css
        modified:   CMS/Models/Data/Db.cs

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        CMS/Areas/Admin/Controllers/ShopController.cs
        CMS/Areas/Admin/Views/Shop/
        CMS/Content/img/
        CMS/Models/Data/CategoryDTO.cs
        CMS/Models/ViewModels/CategoryVM.cs

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Click "Actions" and then "open console" then run the command `git status` and let is know what that says. Also make sure that you have clicked the "save all" button.

Comment: Hey friend, dont know what happened but now I am back at the pc and I can see the changed files and I can commit them. I believe everything was saved already because I was testing the app before trying to commit it, but now I am not sure if clicking "save all" changed anything. If it happens again I will do what you told me and get back to you from the console. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffPuckettII just happened again. It's all saved, I can't even click "save all" because it is all saved already. Did you mean to go to "Actions/ Open Command Prompt"? If so, nothing happens when I click it, I see no console.

Comment: As soon as I make a change in the file, the file appears under changs, and as soon as I save it disappears from there.

Comment: Hmm, seems something glitchy is happening. open up `cmd` all on its own and `cd` to the project folder then run `git status`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII it happened again. the status is in my Q.

Comment: Well now you can at least use the console to `git add .` and `git commit -m "commit message"` which will be better in the long run

Comment: Thanks. Later on they appeared again in the list, and I checked the status and it was the same, weird. Ok I will use the console if all else fails.